# CSS Issue in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Can anyone help me with this? http://173.199.158.105/about-our-company.html shows just fine in Firefox and newer IE versions. But when previewing it in IE6 using Adobe's Browserlab the left sidebar words are cut off. The word customer service is messed up. You can only see "stomer Service". I have no idea what's wrong. Anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: In Chrome, your `.left-column` element has a margin-left of -948px... but in IE6 it has -965px. No idea why, but that's a good place to start.

Comment: How about IE5? You should not support it! If someone uses IE6 just put an conditional HTML and explain that they should not be using it! It's 10 years old for God's sake! Here: http://www.ie6countdown.com/ - it's Microsoft's official site.

Comment: @bobek love that link, they should have it for IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the IE 6 double-margin bug.

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

I also like to add this to my sites...

http://ie6update.com/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, although not a nice one is to use conditional comments for IE6, so loading a separate CSS depending on the users' browser after declaring the normal CSS. Might be more work in the end to maintain but it does solve the bug mentioned by Sparky672.
So something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mydomain.com/index.css"/>
<!--[if IE 6]> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mydomain.com/indexIE6.css"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

See link: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html